# Does Flash of Unstyled Text - FOUT, impacts website performance?

Tags: performance, fonts

Does anyone know why is important to fix FOUT?
Would fixing FOUT help with website performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

FOUT has no impact (a tiny rendering time impact) on performance in terms of load speed, it does affect user experience.

### Longer Answer

A Flash of Unstyled Text (FOUT) itself doesn't affected performance, it is a **consequence** of Web Font performance.

The browser loads it's default font and then when the webfont loads it swaps the new font in. As Web Fonts are normally relatively large files that is where the performance aspect comes in (and people seem to download 10 variations of fonts adding hundreds of KB to the page size).

Now there is a big issue with FOUT / font-swapping. This often results in a layout shift which affects your [Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS)](https://web.dev/cls/) for the site.

It is user experience you are bothered about here with FOUT (which is what CLS is designed to partially measure).

If anything a FOUT is good for performance (load time), the page displays quicker than if you simply hid it until the font loaded in.

#### Solutions?

As with anything there are loads of things you can do to mitigate the issues but they all have tradeoffs.

One example (and what I believe is currently the best solution) is to use a [web safe font set](https://www.cssfontstack.com/) on initial page load.

Then load the custom font(s) using a service worker and store them locally.

Then when the user navigates to a new page (or returns to the site if they immediately leave) you have the font cached locally and can serve it from there.

I have over-simplified the above, it is not a simple thing to implement but it is the best performance to experience balance.

If you really want to push the envelope you might want to look into [Variable Fonts](https://web.dev/variable-fonts/) as [support is pretty good for variable fonts](https://caniuse.com/variable-fonts) and it massively reduces the number of font variations you need (to one).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your professional and well-documented answer, Appreciate it!

Comment: @Sheldortheconqueror yes, we want to load the font into cache on first page load, as we don't want the font to be applied we use a service worker to load the font but not apply it. That way the browser default behaviour of falling back to a font it has can be used `font-family: "custom-font", Century Gothic, sans-serif;`. Initially Century Gothic would show and in the background we load the "custom-font". We can use a few tricks to make sure the font is not applied but is cached, then on the next page load we already have the font cached in the browser so we can use that going forward.